# I need to create a function that will determine how old I will be in a future year

Tags: javascript

I have tried various functions, however I am only able to calculate my age in the present year. Can anyone give example code on how to achieve this?

Here is what I have been most recently tinkering with:

```js
function calculate_age(dob) {
  var diff_ms = Date.now() - dob.getTime();
  var age_dt = new Date(diff_ms);

  return Math.abs(age_dt.getUTCFullYear() - 1997);
}

console.log(calculate_age(new Date(2055, 11, 4)));
```

Comment: Your function takes a parameter called `dob`, which I assume is supposed to stand for Date Of Birth, but you pass it a date way in the future. What input are you actually expecting to receive?

Comment: The function needs two parameters: your date of birth and the future year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function needs a second parameter, the date in the future.

```js
function calculate_age(dob, future_date) {
  var diff_ms = future_date.getTime() - dob.getTime();

  return Math.abs(diff_ms / 365 / 24 / 60 /60 / 1000);
}

console.log(calculate_age(new Date(1961, 2, 31), new Date(2020, 11, 4)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function calculate_age(dob, fd) {
  var diff_ms = fd.getTime() - dob.getTime();

  return Math.floor(diff_ms/(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365.25));
}

console.log(calculate_age(new Date(1980, 11, 4), new Date(2055, 11, 4)));
```

Comment: This calculates your current age, not your age in the future.

Comment: Then the function need two dates as the params